# Setting recovery to simple still results in Log File running computer out of memory with CREATE and INSERT INTO SQL but not SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recently encountered an issue pulling a lot of records from my local database. All tables are in the same database in a local environment on my laptop. I first encountered the problem when trying to do a rather large SQL statement that joins a lot of records between various tables into a single table to be pushed to Azure. What resulted was a memory exception. After looking for the cause I found that the database log file was increasing to well over 80GB. At first I thought it was the `tempDB` database and added the usual advice so that it can autogrow. This did not solve the problem but rather just made my computer run out of memory.

Below I will show you the first three tables that in themselves lead to the error asking for a months worth of data.

Tables

- Shipper: 2 MB, 53180 rows.
- Shipper_Line: 2 MB, 63740 rows
- Shipper_Container: 1229 MB, 28232977 rows

So pretty big but I still would expect SQL Server Management Studio to easily handle these computations using basic joins.

I originally used `CREATE` and `INSERT INTO` statement to populate and existing table. Here is the SQL.

```
--CREATE TABLE FIRST METHOD

--Creates table
CREATE TABLE Shipper_Test
(
    Ship_Date DATETIME,
    Shipper_No VARCHAR(50),
    Truck_Key INT,
    Shipper_Key INT,
    Invoice_Quantity INT,
    Shipper_Line_Key INT,
    Serial_No VARCHAR(25)
)

--declare parameters
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = '20150101'
SET @endDate = '20150130'

--inserts data from sql query below into existing table
INSERT Shipper_Test
(
    Ship_Date,
    Shipper_No,
    Truck_Key,
    Shipper_Key,
    Invoice_Quantity,
    Shipper_Line_Key,
    Serial_No
)

SELECT
    S.Ship_Date,
    S.Shipper_No,
    S.Truck_Key,
    S.Shipper_Key,
    SC.Quantity,
    SL.Shipper_Line_Key,
    SC.Serial_No
FROM Shipper AS S
JOIN Shipper_Line AS SL
    ON SL.Shipper_Key = S.Shipper_Key
JOIN Shipper_Container AS SC
    ON SC.Shipper_Line_Key = SL.Shipper_Line_Key
WHERE Ship_Date >= @startDate 
    AND Ship_Date <= @endDate
```

This is where the problem lies and the temp log file keeps increasing.

I used a SELECT INTO statement and it worked. This is the sql for that.

```
--CREATE TABLE ON THE FLY METHOD
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = '20150101'
SET @endDate = '20150130'

--Uses Select into to create the table as it gets the data
SELECT
    S.Ship_Date,
    S.Shipper_No,
    S.Truck_Key,
    S.Shipper_Key,
    SL.Shipper_Line_Key,
    SC.Serial_No,
    SC.Quantity
INTO NewShipperTable
FROM Shipper AS S
JOIN Shipper_Line AS SL
    ON SL.Shipper_Key = S.Shipper_Key
JOIN Shipper_Container AS SC
    ON SC.Shipper_Line_Key = SL.Shipper_Line_Key
WHERE Ship_Date >= @startDate AND Ship_Date <= @endDate
```

The difference was quite a contrast. Selecting values from 1 - 30 January 2015 using the `CREATE` and `INSERT INTO` method resulted in a time out due to using up all disk space (over 50gb at the point of time out).  Selecting these same values using a `SELECT INTO` statement took 1:00min exactly, and created 144million rows. A simple select statement shows the same result.

I would like to use the existing table if I can. I tried using  `ALTER DATABASE Plex SET RECOVERY SIMPLE` to stop the log file from increasing but it still grew the computer out of memory. I understand that using a `SELECT INTO` produces minimal logging as it is a minimally logged operator and uses a bulk insert. But if I had done the above step I still don't understand why this would have not resulted in improved performance (i.e. the log file still grew). Can someone explain to me what the best method is to approach this. Are my joins and datatables just too big to use a `CREATE` and `INSERT INTO` SQL statement, and thus am forced to use `SELECT INTO`, or am I doing something wrong? It seems to me that 30 million records is not too much at all for SQL Server to handle, so I suspect I am doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also tried using indexes on the parameters in the joins and this did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server (like many relational databases) implements a set of properties recalled by their acronym [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). I'm not going to talk about all of them right now, but the one that matters for this purpose is atomicity. Simply stated, that says that a given operation needs to either happen 100% or 0%. Even if the operation fails somewhere in the middle.

Why this is relevant here is that even though your database is in simple recovery, it needs to log the insertion of the rows into the table. It does so so that in the case of a failure before the operation is complete, it can roll that operation back.

A common workaround for this type of operation is to insert the rows in batches (say 1000 at a time). An easy way and efficient to do that is to use SSIS (if that's available to you). Otherwise, you're going to have to roll your own batching logic into your T-SQL.